# mysql query finding results using joined status table that needs EXIST and NOT EXIST results

Tags: mysql

I have been looking around for ages for a solution to my problem.

I have something that works but i am not sure it is the most efficient way of doing things and can't find anyone trying to do this when googling around.

I have a table with customers and a table with statuses that that customer has had.

If I want to find results where a customer has had a status happen I have managed to get the required results using a join, but sometimes I want to be able to find clients where not only has a status been reached but also where a few other statuses haven't been.

Currently I am doing this with a NOT EXISTS Sub query but it seem a bit slow and thinking about it if I have to check after finding a result that matches the first status through all the results again to see if it doesn't match another it could explain the slowness.

for instance a client could have a status of invoiced and a status of paid.

If I wanted to see which clients have been invoiced thats fine, If I want to see which clients have been invoiced and paid thats fine, but if I wanted to see which clients have been invoiced but NOT paid thats where I start having to use a NOT EXIST subquery

Is there another more efficient way around this? or is this the best way to proceed but I need to sort out how mysql uses indxes with these tables to be more efficient?

I can provide more detail of the actual sql if that helps?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: It really helps if you add the query you are using and the database structure

Answer (score 0):

If this is over multiple clients then the usual solution would be to have a subselect for the status per client and then use LEFT OUTER JOIN to connect this.

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM Clients a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ClientId, COUNT(*) FROM ClientsStatus WHERE Status IN (1,2) GROUP BY ClientId) b
ON a.ClientId = b.ClientId
WHERE b.ClientId IS NULL
```

This (very rough) example is to give you a list of clients who do not have a status of 1 or 2.

You should be able to expand this basic idea to cover the scenarios / data you are dealing with

Edited for below

I have had a play with your SQL. I think you can use a JOIN onto the subselect fairly easily, but this doesn't seem to be checking anything other than whether a claim has had a status of 3 or 95.

```
SELECT claims.ID, claims.vat_rate, claims.com_rate,
claims.offer_val, claims.claim_value, claims.claim_ppi_amount, claims.claim_amount, claims.approx_loan_val, claims.salutationsa, claims.first_namesa, claims.last_namesa, 
clients.salutation, clients.first_name,clients.last_name, clients.phone, clients.phone2, clients.mobile, clients.dob,clients.postcode, clients.address1, clients.address2, clients.town, client_claim_status.person,clients.ID 
AS client_id,claims.ID AS claim_id, claims.date_added AS status_date_added,client_claim_status.date_added AS last_client_claim_status_date_added,work_suppliers.name AS refname, financial_institution.name AS lendname, clients.date_added AS client_date_added,ppi_claim_type_2.claim_type AS ppi_claim_type_name 
FROM claims 
RIGHT JOIN clients ON claims.client_id = clients.ID 
RIGHT JOIN client_claim_status 
ON claims.ID = client_claim_status.claim_id 
AND client_claim_status.deleted != 'yes' 
AND ((client_claim_status.status_id IN (1, 170)) 
AND client_claim_status.date_added < '2012-12-02 00:00:00' ) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT claim_id FROM client_claim_status WHERE status_id IN (3, 95 )) Sub1
ON claims.ID = Sub1.claim_id
LEFT JOIN financial_institution ON claims.claim_against = financial_institution.ID 
LEFT JOIN work_suppliers ON clients.work_supplier_id = work_suppliers.ID 
LEFT JOIN ppi_claim_type_2 ON claims.ppi_claim_type_id = ppi_claim_type_2.ID 
WHERE claims.deleted != 'yes' 
AND Sub1.claim_id IS NULL
ORDER BY last_client_claim_status_date_added DESC
```

I would suggest that you rearrange the code to remove the RIGHT OUTER JOINs though to be honest. Mixing left and right joins up tend to be very confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick response, just so I understand completely, the example you show is where status 1 and 2 haven't been reached so If I need it to work out where, for instance, status 1 and 2 haven't been reached but status 3 has been can I perform  another left join in the same query this time not including WHERE b.ClientId IS NULL so it bring back results where there is a match?

Comment: Yes, almost. You would want to check for IS NOT NULL for the results of the 2nd JOIN, or on the 2nd one you could use an INNER JOIN rather than an OUTER JOIN. Doing a subselect like this is fairly quick (it is done once for the query, rather than once per row in other circumstances). Being a LEFT JOIN it will bring back a row whether or no a match is found on the right of the join and the WHERE is used to exclude those where there is a match found.

Comment: I will let you know how I get on implementing this later when i get into work, thanks again for the help

Comment: If I want to have the status to be IS NOT NULL 3 days after it was set can I just add this to the where statement using the statuses date? and if I have set a status multiple time can I use MAX to only time this after the most recent status?

Comment: For your first point, afraid I would need a lot more info to say either way how you would do it. For the 2nd point you could use similar coding to the above to determine the details of the latest status update (ie, your subselect you use a join against another subselect)

Comment: I have been having a look at my query to see if I can work out how to change it as you have suggested but I think showing you in more detail what I am trying to do especially concerning the secondary questions may help.

Comment: Sorry for smoereason I can't add my code to a comment should it just be surrounded by backticks

Comment: `SELECT claims.ID, claims.vat_rate, claims.com_rate,`

Comment: `claims.offer_val, claims.claim_value, claims.claim_ppi_amount, claims.claim_amount, claims.approx_loan_val, claims.salutationsa, claims.first_namesa, claims.last_namesa,`

Comment: `clients.salutation, clients.first_name,clients.last_name, clients.phone, clients.phone2, clients.mobile, clients.dob,clients.postcode, clients.address1, clients.address2, clients.town, client_claim_status.person,clients.ID`

Comment: `AS client_id,claims.ID AS claim_id, claims.date_added AS status_date_added,client_claim_status.date_added AS last_client_claim_status_date_added,work_suppliers.name AS refname, financial_institution.name AS lendname, clients.date_added AS client_date_added,ppi_claim_type_2.claim_type AS ppi_claim_type_name FROM claims FORCE INDEX (date_added,ID)`

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN clients ON claims.client_id = clients.ID RIGHT JOIN client_claim_status FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (date_added,status_id,claim_id) ON claims.ID = client_claim_status.claim_id AND client_claim_status.deleted !='yes' AND (((client_claim_status.status_id = 1 || client_claim_status.status_id = 170) AND client_claim_status.date_added <'2012-12-02 00:00:00' ) AND NOT EXISTS`

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM client_claim_status WHERE claim_id=claims.ID AND ( status_id = 3 || status_id = 95 )) ) LEFT JOIN financial_institution ON claims.claim_against = financial_institution.ID LEFT JOIN work_suppliers ON clients.work_supplier_id = work_suppliers.ID`

Comment: `LEFT JOIN ppi_claim_type_2 ON claims.ppi_claim_type_id = ppi_claim_type_2.ID WHERE claims.deleted !='yes' ORDER BY last_client_claim_status_date_added DESC`

Comment: Sorry to break it up, it was the only wat I could get it to post the code

Comment: I was trying to improve on the  AND NOT EXISTS section to try and avoid doing the subquery but it may not be the best way/possible with the other functionality I am trying to add.
I want to be able to compare the client_claim_status.date_added <'2012-12-02 00:00:00' to be the date_added of the last row where client_claim_status.status_id = 1 when there may be multiple statuses where client_claim_status.status_id = 1 for this individual claim.

Comment: I have had to FORCE INDEX to try and get mysql to use the right columns as indexes to speed up my search but this maybe because I have not got it setup correctly.
Again any help much appreciated.
Matt @Kickstart

Comment: I have tried running the sql query with explain but I have an error message of

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'claims.ID' in 'where clause' I have tried to get around this but can't find a solution, it maybe because i have claims.ID AS claim_id and then also a column named claim_id in the status table